# Navigation graph with multiple top level destinations and back-key behaviors

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

When I have multiple top level destinations in my navigation graph, and when I click back-key to finish my app, those destinations other than the `startDestination` won't finish but pop the `startDestination` Fragment.

- FragmentA (startDestination) -> finish immediately with back-key
- FragmentB -> back to FragmentA with back-key
- FragmentC -> back to FragmentA with back-key

I've tried `app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph"` and/or `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` but in vain.

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.fragmentA, R.id.fragmentB, R.id.fragmentC)
                        .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();

        NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                toolbar,
                navController,
                appBarConfiguration
        );
    }
}
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of navigation_view body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_view" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_graph:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.stackoverflow.FragmentA"
        android:label="@string/fragmentA">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="(no message)"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/toFragmentAWithMessage1"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentA">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="message 1"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/toFragmentAWithMessage2"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentA">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="message 2"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.stackoverflow.navigationui.FragmentB"
        android:label="@string/fragmentB">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="(no message)"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/toFragmentBWithMessage1"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentB">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="message 1"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/toFragmentBWithMessage2"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentB">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="message 2"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
        android:name="com.stackoverflow.FragmentC"
        android:label="@string/fragmentC">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="(no message)"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/toFragmentCWithMessage1"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentC">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="message 1"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/toFragmentCWithMessage2"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentC">
        <argument
            android:name="message"
            android:defaultValue="message 2"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>

</navigation>
```

I know overriding `OnBackPressedCallback` is a workaround.

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                remove();
                requireActivity().finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there a more fundamental solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove or set **false** to the `app:defaultNavHost` attribute of the NavHostFragment's `<fragment>` in the layout.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="false"
    />
```

[Interact programmatically with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#create_a_navhostfragment)

> Note that `setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost)` lets your NavHost
> intercept system Back button presses. You can also implement this
> behavior in your NavHost XML by adding `app:defaultNavHost="true"`.

[setPrimaryNavigationFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setPrimaryNavigationFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment))

> Set a currently active fragment in this FragmentManager as the primary navigation fragment.
>
> The primary navigation fragment's child FragmentManager will be called
> first to process delegated navigation actions such as
> `FragmentManager.popBackStack()` if no ID or transaction name is
> provided to pop to. Navigation operations outside of the fragment
> system may choose to delegate those actions to the primary navigation
> fragment as returned by
> `FragmentManager.getPrimaryNavigationFragment()`.

Because of your setting true to `app:defaultNavHost`, your NavHost intercepts back-key presses and leads to pop the startDestination FragmentA.